# What is proper way of comparing strings in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I cannot figure out how to compare strings in Clojure. Given this basic function:

```
(defn login [username]
  (let [x (username)]
    (if (identical? x "John")
     "Welcome"
     "incorrect username")))
```

I keep getting this error message: java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn when I call the function. What is the best way of comparing strings in Clojure?

Comment: Don't call `username` as a function: that's what `(username)` does. The way you are comparing strings is *also* wrong (see Chris Murphy's answer), but the error you're getting is long before you actually attempt to compare it. Just use `username` without parens.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message you are getting is because `username` that is coming into your function is a String, and you are trying to invoke it (without any params). You don't really need the `let` form at all. Instead of `x` put `username`.

All immutable values respond to using `=`:

`(= username "John")`

`=` actually checks the value, rather than some 'in memory pointer' notion.